# Rounding, variable from a .txt in Python 3 and extra

Tags: python, python-3.x, counter, division, rounding-error

```
if op in ["/"]:
    # rounding does not rounds half up so I imported a module
    from decimal import Decimal, ROUND_HALF_UP, ROUND_HALF_DOWN
    Decimal(str(answer)).quantize(Decimal("1.11"), rounding=ROUND_HALF_UP)
    Decimal(str(given_answer)).quantize(Decimal("1.11"), rounding=ROUND_HALF_UP)
print("correct {}".format(answer, ".2f"))
```

> 49//34=?1.44
>
> correct 1
>
> Wrong answer!

I want it to have the right answer as 3.56 if the real answer is 3.55865465. What am I doing wrong?

[image: Written text file with python]

Comment: 49/34 is 1.44 Why do you want it to be `3.56`? and how is that the right answer?

Comment: I don't say that i want 3.56 for 49/34. "I want it to have the right answer as 3.56 if the real answer is 3.55865465."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the last line to the following:

```
print("correct {:.2f}".format(answer))
```

Comment: The real value is 2,777777777778 and i want the real number rounded to 2.78 is there a way to do that? Thanks for the other parth.

Comment: yes, you need to specify that your input is float. for example:
answer = float(100) / 36
print("correct {:.2f}".format(answer))